# Many to Many relation ordering by created_at field of pivot table

Tags: many-to-many, eloquent

I having build a nice CRM system, where I have linked Contacts with Organization

In my contact model I have:

```
public function organizations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Organization')
      ->withPivot('ContractStatus')
      ->withTimestamps()
      ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

The problem is that it is ordering on the creating date of the organization table now.
But to echo a list of job history for each contact, I want to order on the created_at field of the pivot table, since that is the date the contract between Contact en Organization was made.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, pivot table fields on the relation are aliased with prefix `pivot_`, so they don't collide with related table fields.

That being said, you need this:

```
public function organizations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Organization')
      ->withPivot('ContractStatus')
      ->withTimestamps()
      ->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Mind that this will work only when you use `withTimestamps()` as well, otherwise you will get `unknown column` db error.

---

Edit: As per OP comments, you can alway use traditional approach and prefix the field with pivot table name:

```
public function organizations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Organization')
      ->withPivot('ContractStatus')
      ->withTimestamps()
      ->orderBy('PIVOT_TABLE.created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Comment: I solved it with orderBy('pivottablename.created_at', 'desc'). I didn't know they prefix the table fields also

Comment: Yes, of course explicitly referenced field is another option.